# Return values from database in original datatypes (Kohana ORM)

Tags: mysql, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db, kohana-3.2

I have a column in database table `active` which should return whether user has confirmed mail or not. It is tinyint(1) and if it is set 0 and I test it strictly against FALSE operator doesn't return TRUE. I use ORM to communicate with database.

This is set in MySQL database:
active  tinyint(1)          Yes 0

```
if ($user->active === FALSE) // returns FALSE
if ($user->active === '0') // returns TRUE
```

I've been searching in API for solution and in Database class there was already tinyint datatype.

Do I have to use == instead of === or there is something else I could do?

Comment: FALSE is not identical to 0! - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Yes, it is, when 0 isn't integer or string, but boolean. That is what I want to do - I want to return value from database as BOOL and not string.

Comment: Not it is not. Besides you have said you are returning the data from a TINYINT(1) not a BOOLEAN. MySQL does not implement BOOLEAN anyway. It is a synonym for TINYINT(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep things consistent, casting db data to PHP equivalents was removed since 3.0, meaning you're right - no strict comparison :)

What you can do if you really want it is overwrite `ORM::_load_values()` combined with `ORM::list_columns()` to cast to 'right' data types (that is - if you're staying with the MySQL driver because moving to PDO will break things).

Comment: Hvala :)
Ok, I am going to use loose comparison. I considered that as a bad practice, but this is easier than changing Kohana core files.